# showing two ul tabs at the same time using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem when using two ul tab elements on the same page. They both work, however, if the other ul tab element is pressed on the second ul element, the first one disapears.

For [jsfiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/eromreve/aqLN2/)

I am pretty confident that the problem is, when it hides the div:

```
       for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
```

However, i do not seem to be able to solve this problem with the various things i have tried.
All help appreciated.

Best Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are looping in whole contentdivs and setting clicked one to show and rest to hide.

What you should do is keep two tab grouped in two separated divs and then loop through the childnodes of div of which li element has been clicked.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/aqLN2/6/)

In show function

```
 function showTab() {

  **// this div contatins one tab group**       
  var parentDiv = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  **// loop only through the div of which li tab has been clicked**

  for ( var i = 0; i < parentDiv.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( parentDiv.childNodes[i].nodeName == "DIV" ) {
          var id = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getAttribute('id');

          // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
          // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
          if ( id == selectedId ) {
              tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
              contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
          } else {
              tabLinks[id].className = '';
              contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
          }
    }
  }
  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}
```

And in html

```
<div id="tab-group1"> code block for tab 1 </div>
<div id="tab-group2"> code block for tab 2 </div>
```

Comment: Hey Sami,
Awesome, thanks for your help. Is it possible to make the two tabs both start open, so that tab group 1 and group 2 both have an open tab when the page is loaded? It must have something to do with this function with the following comment in the jsfiddle: // Hide all content divs except the first

Comment: @Patrick see the updated jsfiddle. Also try to see how can you reduce code repetition for example you were looping different times to assign different value which can be done in one loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate processing and ids for both **ul**s and tab elements themselves.
My guess is - it just processes both tab-sets in one function, meaning that only 1 tab can be visible at a time (hides the tab from 1st ul to show tab in 2nd ul).

Try separating the processing of those and everything should work.

Comment: Hi Jurijs, Thanks for your answer. How do you suggest I do that? Is it something you can show in the jsfiddle if you have a minute or two to spare?

Comment: @Patrick Ok, so in your code, you're sort of referencing tabs and stuff using one array - tabLinks, and reference those by doing tabLinks[id]. Meaning that all of your tabs and all of your tab buttons are stored in 1 array, which is not what you want. What you would  need to do to make those separate, try saving and referencing objects in the array like tabLinks[tabId][id]. That way you get a 2 dimensional array with separate sets for each tabId (each ul in this case), that you run the function for. 

Do that for all the references to contentDivs and tabLinks arrays.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I have now done as you suggested, but still with no luck. What you are saying makes completely sense, but the script does not seem to agree. The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eromreve/aqLN2/2/

I do not get why the id variable is passed trough the functions like a global variable when it is not defined, and why my tabId is then also not passed trough. In the showtab() it will not accept tabId as a variable it seems. Hoping you have more to share with me :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that that's a different function. Well then define the tabId in ShowTab function as follows:

var tabId = this.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id');